# Error showing while starting apache and mysql from autostart in xampp?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I was trying to setup autostart modules on clicking of config in xampp control panel. but its pops out an error message saying:

> "Error:Cannot create file "C:\xampp\xampp-control.ini". Access denied.

Comment: Does [this](https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=260393&sid=4cd9f4c55144461073ff3a4c068ba1c4) help?

Comment: Yes, when we start xampp control panel with 'Run as administrator' then it works properly.

Comment: Can you check this tutorial, may be helpful: [Error: Cannot create file xampp-control.ini Access is denied](https://devnote.in/error-cannot-create-file-xampp-control-ini-access-is-denied/)

Answer (score 0):

Certified that your XAMPP has administrator access. For that go to the local where XAMPP is installed (normally C:\xampp for Windows users) and find the application xampp-control.exe. Open it with the right button and go to **properties**, **compatibility** and mark the option **'Run this program as an Administrator'** or something like that.